# How to define space as a variable?

Tags: spacing, macros

I want to define a command that makes vertical space like `\\[30pt]` variable. I want to define the string between the brackets so that it is variable like `20pt` or `1.5cm`.
Thus I would be able to define my desired vertical space just once.

Comment: Can you please explain better what's your aim?

Comment: @Werner It seems that `\\` gives you double backlash while I have got a single one. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: See [this comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box/2749#comment8717_208). You need <bt><bt>\\<bt><bt> (where <bt>=`).

Comment: @Werner Thank you! Curiosities of MathJax conquer me from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want something like

```
\def\myspace{\vspace{20pt}}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\myspace}{\vspace*{1.5cm}}
```

It will be used in vertical mode, e.g. `\myspace` in the paragraph will move the next line of this paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However \\[30pt] does two things: new line and vertical space. Is it possible to combine them in a way as you suggested?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but using `\\`` (Double backlash. How to obtain it in a comment?!) to obtain a new line outside special envirenments, e.g. `tabular` is a bad idea. If you want to use your vertical space in a tabular-like environment, you can simply define, say,  `\def\1{\\[30pt]}` and use `\1` instead of `\\`.

Comment: Use “double backquote, double backslash, double backquote”: ``\\``

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I will remember it now, I hope.